# SQL query to avoid duplicates and order by a row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Need a SQL query using joins
I need a help

Table name: RVW_TSK

**RVW_ID UPC_CD   CMPL_DATE**
00001   10101010   10-10-2009
00002   10101010   13-10-2009
00003   20202020   5-11-2008
00004   20202020   8-11-2008

Expected result is like:

```
RVW_ID  UPC_CD    CMPL_DATE
00002   10101010  13-10-2009
00004   20202020  8-11-2008
```

I want the latest one (from CMPL_DATE) and no duplication of UPC_CD.
Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: What database product and version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a straight forward group by unless i am reading something wrong here.
Since i dont have any database to test it now..cannot vouch for the exact syntax but here goes...assuming that the CMPL_DATE is a datetime field. It might need some conversions etc if it is a string

```
Select MAX(RVW_ID), UPC_CD, MAX(CMPL_DATE)
FROM RVW_TSK
GROUP BY UPC_CD
```

Comment: This Assumes RVW_ID is ever increasing integer !

Comment: Yup. It does assume that. If it isnt, then this will not suffice. The _ID in the field name just makes me jump automatically to conclusions.. Force of habit, i am afraid :-)

Answer (score 3):

If rvw_id and cmpl_date have the same order, you can get away with:

```
select max(rvw_id), upc_cd, max(cmpl_date)
from rvw_tsk
group by upc_cd
```

If not, you have to do something slightly fancier, as in Bharat's or Baaju's answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   B.RVW_ID, B.UPC_CD, B.CMPL_DATE 
FROM     (SELECT UPC_CD, MAX(CMPL_DATE) CMPL_DATE
          FROM RVW_TSK
          GROUP BY UPC_CD)TBL JOIN RVW_TSK B
ON        TBL.UPC_CD = B.UPC_CD AND TBL.CMPL_DATE = B.CMPL_DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  MAX(RVW_ID), distinct UPC_CD, max(CMPL_DATE) from RVW_TSK group by UPC_CD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT rvw_id,
               upc_cd,
               cmpl_date,
               RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY upc_cd ORDER BY cmpl_date DESC)
                  my_rank
          FROM rvw_tsk)
 WHERE my_rank = 1;
```

Comment: No need to use JOINs, you have only to use the Oracle Analytical Function called RANK.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select RVW_ID, UPC_CD, CMPL_DATE
From RVW_TSK As T
Where T.CMPL_DATE = (
                        Select Max(CMPL_DATE)
                        From RVW_TSK As T1
                        Where T1.UPC_CD= T.UPC_CD
                        )
```

This assumes that for a given UPC_CD, that the dates are unique. It is unclear from your post whether this is true and if not how duplicates should be handled.